# MYSQL - How to SELECT CASE (two tables, if not present in one, check the other)

Tags: mysql, select, case

What I have is two tables inside of a mysql database.

One table contains the field with the value `"example@example.com"`

The other table does not...

What I would like to do is check both tables for a field with a value that matches `"example@example.com"`.

Here is my query which does not work:

```
(#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 13)

SELECT CASE WHEN
EXISTS (
    SELECT address, suburb, city, postCode, province
    FROM user_postal
    INNER JOIN user_info ON user_postal.id = user_info.id
    WHERE user_info.emailContact = 'example@example.com'
)
OR EXISTS (
    SELECT address, suburb, city, postCode, province
    FROM user_postal
    INNER JOIN user_business_info ON user_postal.id = user_business_info.id
    WHERE user_business_info.emailContact = 'example@example.com'
)
```

I would like to return the values of the fields `address, suburb, city, postCode, province` that match the id of the user with the email `example@example.com`. (This could be in either of the two tables but it is surely in one or the other)

Could anyone enlighten me as to where I am going wrong with this? Any information in this regard would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about this:

```
SELECT address, suburb, city, postCode, province
FROM user_postal
INNER JOIN user_info ON user_postal.id = user_info.id
WHERE user_info.emailContact = 'example@example.com'

UNION

SELECT address, suburb, city, postCode, province
FROM user_postal
INNER JOIN user_business_info ON user_postal.id = user_business_info.id
WHERE user_business_info.emailContact = 'example@example.com'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT address, suburb, city, postCode, province 
FROM user_postal
        INNER JOIN user_business_info ON (user_postal.id = user_business_info.id AND user_info.emailContact = 'example@example.com')
                                        OR (user_postal.id = user_info.id AND user_business_info.emailContact = 'example@example.com')
```

Answer (score 0):

This is where you want to use a [`UNION`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/union.html).

Comment: Thank you for your input, could you explain why I union would be better in this case? I have adapted the query from one the selects a case of 1 or 0 based on whether there is a match or not... But in this case why a union?